# Adding comment to specific post using id with Angularjs and PHP

Tags: php, angularjs

I am new to Angular and am struggling to add a comment to a specific post that is being displayed from a database. 
Under the post I have a hidden comment area that shows when pressing the button.
I then want to be able to add the comment to the post the comment area is attached too.
It seems like it is not getting the id but I can't find how to solve it.
It is doing the show/hide, and I am getting the "data inserted" in the console log so I'm guessing the problem is with the PHP?

Angular code

```js
app.controller('meetings', function($scope, $http) {
$scope.meetings_insertdata = function() {
$http.post ("meetings_insert.php",{'meetings_commentdate':$scope.meetings_commentdate,'meetings_comment':$scope.meetings_comment})
window.location.reload();
console.log("data inserted");
    };
});



app.controller('show_hide', function ($scope) {
            $scope.Hidden = true;
            $scope.ShowHide = function () {
                $scope.Hidden = $scope.Hidden ? false : true;
            }

   });
```

meetings_insert.php

```
<?php

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$meetings_comment = $data->meetings_comment;
$meetings_commentdate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$meetings_entry = $_GET['id'];

mysql_connect("localhost","user","password");
mysql_select_db("mdb_rh316");



mysql_query("UPDATE project_meetings SET (meetings_comment, meetings_commentdate) = ('$meetings_comment','$meetings_commentdate') WHERE meetings_entry = '$meetings_entry'");

?>
```

HTML code

```
<div class="entrybox" ng-controller="meetings">
<?php 
mysql_connect("localhost","user","password");
mysql_select_db("mdb_rh316");

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM project_meetings ORDER BY meetings_date DESC");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<table>";
        echo "<tr><td>" ?>Added: <? echo $row['meetings_date'] . $row['meetings_entry'] . "<br/>" . $row['meetings_content']."</td></tr>";
        echo "<tr><td>" ?><br/><span class="emp">Comment: <?
        echo $row['meetings_commentdate']."<br/>" . $row['meetings_comment']."</td></tr>";
        echo "<tr><td>"?></span>
        <div ng-controller="show_hide">
        <input type="button" class="previous_add" value="Add comment" ng-click="ShowHide()" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <div ng-hide = "Hidden">
<form method="post" action="meetings_insert.php?id=<? echo $row['$meetings_entry']?>"> 
<textarea class="textarea" placeholder="Add your comment here.." type="text" ng-model="meetings_comment" name="meetings_comment"></textarea><br/>
<input type="button" class="button" value= "Add" ng-click="meetings_insertdata()"/>
</form>
        </div>
    </div>
</td></tr><br/><?;

}

echo "</table>";
?>
</div>
```

Comment: I might be missing something, but you are POSTing to meetings_insert.php and in your PHP you have this line: "$meetings_entry = $_GET['id'];"  Is $_GET['id'] actually a value?  Where would it have come from?

Comment: UPDATE: I see you have a form action where you would be doing a GET on meetings_insert.php in the form, but since you are responding to ng-click and POSTing to meetings_insert.php, I'm guessing "id" is not there. Ensure your php.ini has error logging set up and use this to see what's coming in to your PHP call: error_log(serialize($_POST)); error_log(serialize($_GET))

Answer (score 0):

Pass 'id' into the meetings_insertdata function:

```html
<form method="post" action="">
  <textarea class="textarea" placeholder="Add your comment here.." type="text" ng-model="meetings_comment" name="meetings_comment"></textarea>
  <br/>
  <input type="button" class="button" value="Add" ng-click="meetings_insertdata(<? echo $row['$meetings_entry']?>)" />
</form>
```

Receive it in the AngularJS function below:

```js
app.controller('meetings', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.meetings_insertdata = function(id) {
    $http.post("meetings_insert.php", {
      'meetings_commentdate': $scope.meetings_commentdate,
      'meetings_comment': $scope.meetings_comment,
      'meetings_event': id
    })
    window.location.reload();
    console.log("data inserted");
  };
});
```

Then, pick up 'id' from the posted value ($data->meetings_event)

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$meetings_comment = $data->meetings_comment;
$meetings_commentdate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$meetings_entry = $data->meetings_event;

Comment: Let us know if this solves your issue or if you need a bit more help to get this going.  If you do need more help, comment with what you tried, the results, and we can get you more help from there.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it is still not doing it.
I got rid of the show_hide controller to see if that had anything to do with it but it didnt.

I also added 
.success(function(data,status,headers,config){
window.location.reload();
console.log("data inserted");
 });
to the meetings controller to see where it is going wrong, and the console log is putting out "data inserted" still.

Comment: I also tried another thing which is adding the comment to the correct place, but is far from ideal as it requires entering the id manually.

form in the HTML
<div ng-controller="meetings">
<form method="post"> 
enter id: <? echo $row['meetings_entry']?> <input ng-model="meetings_entry"/><br/>
<textarea ng-model="meetings_comment" name="meetings_comment"></textarea><br/>
<input type="button" class="previous_add" value= "Add" ng-click="meetings_insertdata()"/>
</form>

Comment: php
$meetings_commentdate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$meetings_comment = $data->meetings_comment;
$meetings_entry = $data->meetings_entry;

mysql_query("UPDATE project_meetings SET meetings_commentdate ='$meetings_commentdate', meetings_comment='$meetings_comment' WHERE meetings_entry = '$meetings_entry'");

Comment: Angular
app.controller('meetings', function($scope, $http) {
$scope.meetings_insertdata = function() {
$http.post ("meetings_insert.php",{'meetings_commentdate':$scope.meetings_commentdate,'meetings_comment':$scope.meetings_comment, 'meetings_entry':$scope.meetings_entry})

Comment: Given the multiple coding contexts, and inline code in comments, it's a little difficult to follow where you are. What was the result when you tried my answer above?  Passing in the id as an argument to the meetings_insertdata should be received into the function and that should pass along the value to the PHP function.  I recommend starting by getting that working and move on to the next part of the problem.  Also, use curl, or another command-line tool, to unit test your PHP code so you are convinced your PHP is solid, and you know exactly which parameters (GET or POST) your PHP is handling.

Comment: An example of using curl to POST data: `curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{ "id":123,"meetings_comment":"my comment"}' http://localhost/mydirectory/meetings_insert.php.php`

Comment: When I tried your answer it just updated the page but no information was added to the database and no error message was displayed.

Comment: The php should be working as I can get the meeting_entry from the database to display on the same page, and the same query works when the id is entered manually.

Comment: There are three transfers in the process: html > JS > PHP > MySQL.  Start with PHP.  Add debug information and view the results of the values coming in to the PHP code.  Are you able to see the results of an error_log($value) command?  Is logging turned on?

Comment: I have never heard of curl before, where do I place it?

Comment: curl is a command-line tool for posting data to a URL.  Look online for help on installing it for your environment.